# jquery *:not() isn't selecting everything but what's in parantheses as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to append some html to a page when a div is clicked on, then when any other part of the page is clicked on (except the newly attached div and the div that was clicked that attached it) remove the attached div. For some reason my `:not()` selector isn't working as I'd expect it to.

```
 $("*").on("click", "body:not(._tlh_dropdown, ._tlh_dropdown_content)", function () {
   // ... remove previously attached div
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qUHAB/5/

How can I remove this div when anything is clicked on except for the two classes `_tlh_dropdown` and `_tlh_dropdown_content`?

Comment: That's not what's in your jsfiddle!

Comment: @Pointy yeah, I was playing around with some new idea. Forgot to update the question before submitting. Editing now. Thanks!

Comment: the body will never be `._tlh_dropdown, ._tlh_dropdown_content` unless it can possibly have those classes, therefore the event will always be triggered. Instead, test what event.target is inside the click event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well:

```
$("*").on("click", "body:not(._tlh_dropdown, ._tlh_dropdown_content)", function () {
```

is almost certainly not what you want.  That adds an event handler for every element on the page, asking it to check for events from the `<body>` to have bubbled up. It kind-of makes no sense.

And

```
$("body").on("click", "*:not(._tlh_dropdown, ._tlh_dropdown_content)", function () {
```

will have problems *with your test page* because there's nothing else in the `<body>` but your header.

Change it to the second thing above (like it was in your original question), and then add a `<div>` with some text in it after the content that's there, and then click in that. Alternatively, change it to:

```
$(document).on("click", "*:not(._tlh_dropdown, ._tlh_dropdown_content)", function () {
```

and that'll catch events bubbling up from the `<body>`.

*edit* — if you go with `$(document)`, it'd also be a good idea (especially if you want it to work :-)  to add an "event" parameter to the handler functions and, in each, to call

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

In the first event handler (the one that opens up the extra content), that will prevent the second handler from running when the "click" on the header bubbles up to the body. For the second handler, stopping propagation isn't as important but it'll avoid redundant attempts to close the added content.

*edit some more* — see the comments below; the "close" handler has some subtleties that make implementing it with the "on" selector approach kind-of problematic.

Comment: why not just `$('body').on('click', function(e){ if ($(e.target).hasClass('._tlh_dropdown') || $(e.target).hasClass('._thl_dropdown_content')){ }else{ } });`?

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I did an update fiddle, where I increased html and body css to have width and height set up at `100%` so I could test if it anywhere was clicked without adding the extra div. Do you think that works as well? http://jsfiddle.net/qUHAB/7/ It's still removing the container div when the container div itself is clicked. Which really confuses me. Can you see why?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yes, it'd certainly be possible to do that too.

Comment: @thomas see my note about calling ".stopPropagation()"

Comment: @Ohgodwhy in fact that's a much better way to do it :)

Comment: @thomas the problem is that clicks in the added content are  bubbling up to the body before propagation can be stopped. I'll modify the fiddle as per Ohgodwhy's suggestion and post it.

Comment: I've added that http://jsfiddle.net/qUHAB/8/ , yet it seems still not to work. Just curious, why do you say @Ohgodwhy's answer is much better?

Comment: @thomas because it allows the handler to get in there in time to stop the event from propagating.  [Here is another version](http://jsfiddle.net/UrNUM/) and I think it works better.

Comment: that's really cool. thank you. does just putting `return` in `if (!$('body').hasClass('tlh-open')) return;` do the same thing as `return false;`? Does that just stop execution. I see both sometimes..

Comment: Well just plain `return` makes the handler do nothing but it won't cancel event propagation or default behaviors, while `return false` will do that.

Comment: hmm..interesting. how come adding a console.log("Test") after `if (!$('body').hasClass('tlh-open')) return;` it doesn't fire when I click on the `_tlh_dropdown` div? http://jsfiddle.net/UrNUM/1/ sorry to keep pestering you..